# How to compute cluster distance from each record using KMEANS?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I applied Kmeans algorithm on my dataset with two clusters. My dataset shape is (506,13). How to get the cluster distance from each record?

I have tried using Euclidean distance for the cluster centers but I want to know the distance from each record to both the clusters.

```
model= KMeans(n_clusters=2)
model.fit(X)
print(model.cluster_centers_)

[3.88774444e-01 1.55826558e+01 8.42089431e+00 7.31707317e-02
5.11847425e-01 6.38800542e+00 6.06322493e+01 4.44127154e+00
4.45528455e+00 3.11926829e+02 1.78092141e+01 3.81042575e+02
1.04174526e+01]
[1.22261690e+01 3.01980663e-14 1.84518248e+01 5.83941606e-02
6.70102190e-01 6.00621168e+00 8.99678832e+01 2.05447007e+00
2.32700730e+01 6.67642336e+02 2.01963504e+01 2.91039051e+02
1.86745255e+01]

**actual results:**
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
dists = euclidean_distances(model.cluster_centers_)
array([[  0.        , 369.34000546],
[369.34000546,   0.        ]])

**Expected results:**

rows cluster_1_distance  cluster_2_distance
 0        0.78                 0.89
 1        0.53                 0.66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cdist` function from [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) library.

As stated in the reference, it takes 2 matrices, and returns distances between each pair of the two matrices. You can use `metric` argument to specify the type of distance function you want.

In your case,

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
dists = cdist(X,model.cluster_centers_,metric='euclidean') #shape of dists : (506,2)
```

Comment: I have tried with cdist as you mentioned but it is giving an error, 
`X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5),columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
 
 model= KMeans(n_clusters=2)
 
 dists = cdist(f1,model.cluster_centers_,metric='euclidean')
 
AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'`

Comment: @ShihabShahriar `model = model.fit(X)` and `model.fit(X)` are equivalent.

Comment: yes.. i've realized it just few minutes back...thanks anyway